# Unable to Select Mailing Recipients

Tags: civimail, mailing, 4.6, javascript

CiviCRM 4.6.10 and 4.6.11
Joomla 2.5.28
No Civi extensions installed
Have tried different templates, disabling Joomla plugins, switching WYSIWYG editors, etc.

Rather extensive error log in web inspector points to js errors in bower components and angular. I can temporarily set CiviMail back to legacy mode, but not a good long term solution. Please advise if I should open an issue on Jira.

```
[Error] Error: b.indexOf is not a function. (In 'b.indexOf("[object Object])', 'b.indexOf' is undefined)
b@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:6995
initContainerWidth@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:7176
initContainer@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:13032
init@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:1:19485
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:31032
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:2979
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:839
select2@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:30777
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/Common.js?r=9T92B:44:12
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:2979
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:839
crmSelect2@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/Common.js?r=9T92B:41:20
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/Common.js?r=9T92B:52:15
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:2979
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:839
crmEntityRef@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/js/Common.js?r=9T92B:45:74
init@http://domainname.net/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=9T92B:60:37
link@http://domainname.net/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=9T92B:61:5
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:98
Z@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:150
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:256
g@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:51:336
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:50:445
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:52:323
h@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:56:323
link@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:239:290
Z@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:150
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:256
g@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:51:336
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:200
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:66:210
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:112:183
$eval@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:126:250
$digest@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:123:370
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:126:344
e@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:40:79
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:44:163
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    Z
    I
    g
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    h
    link
    Z
    I
    g
    I
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    $eval
    $digest
    (anonymous function)
    e
    (anonymous function)
[Error] Error: b.indexOf is not a function. (In 'b.indexOf("[object Object])', 'b.indexOf' is undefined)
b@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:6995
initContainerWidth@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:7176
initContainer@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:13032
init@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:1:19485
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:31032
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:2979
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:839
select2@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:30777
init@http://domainname.net/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=9T92B:58:32
link@http://domainname.net/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=9T92B:59:5
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:98
Z@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:150
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:256
g@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:51:336
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:200
g@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:51:336
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:50:445
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:52:323
h@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:56:323
link@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:239:290
Z@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:150
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:256
g@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:51:336
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:200
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:66:210
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:112:183
$eval@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:126:250
$digest@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:123:370
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:126:344
e@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:40:79
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:44:163
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    Z
    I
    g
    I
    g
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    h
    link
    Z
    I
    g
    I
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    $eval
    $digest
    (anonymous function)
    e
    (anonymous function)
[Error] Error: b.indexOf is not a function. (In 'b.indexOf("[object Object])', 'b.indexOf' is undefined)
b@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:6995
initContainerWidth@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:7176
initContainer@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:13032
init@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:1:19485
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:31032
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:2979
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:839
select2@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:30777
init@http://domainname.net/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=9T92B:58:32
link@http://domainname.net/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=9T92B:59:5
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:98
Z@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:150
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:256
g@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:51:336
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:200
g@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:51:336
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:50:445
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:52:323
h@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:56:323
link@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:239:290
Z@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:150
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:256
g@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:51:336
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:200
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:66:210
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:112:183
$eval@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:126:250
$digest@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:123:370
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:126:344
e@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:40:79
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:44:163
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    Z
    I
    g
    I
    g
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    h
    link
    Z
    I
    g
    I
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    $eval
    $digest
    (anonymous function)
    e
    (anonymous function)
[Error] Error: b.indexOf is not a function. (In 'b.indexOf("[object Object])', 'b.indexOf' is undefined)
b@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:6995
initContainerWidth@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:7176
initContainer@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:13032
init@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:1:19485
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:31032
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:2979
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:839
select2@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:30777
init@http://domainname.net/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=9T92B:58:32
link@http://domainname.net/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=9T92B:59:5
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:98
Z@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:150
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:256
g@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:51:336
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:200
g@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:51:336
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:50:445
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:52:323
h@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:56:323
link@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:239:290
Z@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:150
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:256
g@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:51:336
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:200
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:66:210
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:112:183
$eval@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:126:250
$digest@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:123:370
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:126:344
e@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:40:79
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:44:163
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    Z
    I
    g
    I
    g
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    h
    link
    Z
    I
    g
    I
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    $eval
    $digest
    (anonymous function)
    e
    (anonymous function)
[Error] Error: b.indexOf is not a function. (In 'b.indexOf("[object Object])', 'b.indexOf' is undefined)
b@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:6995
initContainerWidth@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:7176
initContainer@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:22728
init@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:1:19485
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:31032
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:2979
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:839
select2@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:30777
link@http://domainname.net/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=9T92B:119:19
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:98
Z@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:70:150
I@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:59:256
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:66:210
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:112:183
$eval@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:126:250
$digest@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:123:370
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:126:344
e@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:40:79
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:44:163
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    Z
    I
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    $eval
    $digest
    (anonymous function)
    e
    (anonymous function)
[Error] Error: b.indexOf is not a function. (In 'b.indexOf("%")', 'b.indexOf' is undefined)
b@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:6995
initContainerWidth@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:7176
initContainer@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:13032
init@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:1:19485
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:31032
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:2979
each@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?r=9T92B:2:839
select2@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/select2/select2.min.js?r=9T92B:2:30777
http://domainname.net/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=9T92B:89:13336
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:139:176
e@http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:40:79
http://domainname.net/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js?r=9T92B:44:163
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    (anonymous function)
    e
    (anonymous function)
[Warning] Invalid CSS property declaration at: * (administrator, line 1)
```

Comment: Let me make sure I am understanding correctly. You are trying to use CiviMail, but it is not auto-loading the recipients as it should? If I am correct on that, when I had this problem after an upgrade, I resolved it by going to Administer>System Settings>Cleanup Caches and Update Paths, then click the Cleanup Caches button (do not update the paths).  You indicated that you do not have any extensions installed.  All those errors look like they can be resolved by installing angular-profiles

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problems, but it was in drupal, not joomla. So this is probably not the same issue. For me, the final culprit was a Civicrm extension: "pogstone fancy tokens".

Comment: Thanks Cullen, but we don't have any Civi extensions on this site. Glad that you were able to fix your site, though!